# Can't install 12.04 to flash using unetbootin.exe

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install 12.04 to flash using unetbootin.exe. It copies files ok but during the install phase get the following error.

un3142.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience.

The number varies but always fails at about 33%. I have tried loading Fedor, same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [LinuxLive USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) instead of unetbootin.